# numpy change specific value to null gives error "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer"

Tags: python, numpy, nan, mask

I have numpy array with the shape of (1,5,10).

```
array([[[ -5,  -5,  -5,  -5, 120, 116, 118, 118,  -5,  -5],
        [ -5,  -5, 126, 127, 125, 118, 118, 123,  -5,  -5],
        [ -5, 121, 125, 118, 115, 115, 121, 121, 114, 127],
        [112, 118, 108, 111, 110, 112, 104, 102, 103,  -5],
        [105, 108, 107,  -5,  -5,  -5,  -5,  -5,  -5,  -5]]], dtype=int16)
```

I would like to change all the -5 into np.nan value.
In order to do that I have written this code:

```
out_image[out_image == (-5)] = np.nan
```

but that gives me an error:

> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Why do I get this error? and how can I replace the values into nan?

Comment: Your array is `dtype=int16`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to convert it to `float` first.

```
out_image = out_image.astype('float')
out_image[out_image== -5] = np.NAN
```

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it as `out_image` were a `pandas.Dataframe`. Instead you can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method like this:

```
np.where(out_image == -5, np.NaN, out_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue ,when I was storing my Data into BigInt column and to counter the issue to store Nan/Null/None into int/BigInt datatype I have used below approach.

```python
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].convert_dtypes()
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype('Int64')
```

using first line code I have converted all values into float and then with below
code I have converted back everything into Int64

you can directly jump to second part for me i have to do some other changes into my column values that's why I have used convert_dtypes()